# How do I use RegEx (in JS) to alter multiple dollar amounts to display two decimal places and commas (where required)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this RegEx statement…

> `/\((\$.*?)\)/g`

…to locate all parenthetical dollar amounts found in a string like this…

> "My 3 meals were fairly cheap ($45) but I ended up spending a lot more ($1532.01) than I anticipated."

What RegEx statement would amend the source sentence so that all of the parenthetical amounts were properly formatted to include two decimal places and commas where needed?

> "My 3 meals were fairly cheap ($45.00) but I ended up spending a lot more ($1,532.01) than I anticipated."

To clarify, the objective is *not* to extract the values with the proper formatting (e.g., in an array); it's to change the sentence so that it shows the proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const str = 'My 3 meals were fairly cheap ($45) but I ended up spending a lot more ($1532.01) than I anticipated';
const regex = /\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g;
console.log( str.replace(regex, (m,g) => '$' + Number(g).toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 })) )
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LGaYbS/3).

Output:

```
My 3 meals were fairly cheap ($45.00) but I ended up spending a lot more ($1,532.01) than I anticipated
```

The `\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` regex matches a `$` and then captures into Group 1 any one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits.

In the replacement, a callback arrow function is used to append the modified number to the `$` char to form the replacement string.